# Wifi dropping on Lenovo G50-70

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, laptop, realtek

I'm having problems with my WiFi on a Lenovo G50-70 which uses the Realtek RTL8723BE chip. After a certain time it drops. I then have to reboot the whole system to get the Wifi functioning again.

Noteworthy is that it happens every time in a Skype conference after like 27 minutes.

I found some bug reports on launchpad and tried several suggestions. I upgraded the kernel to the latest version 3.18. Also I added the following options in `/etc/modeprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`:

```
options rtl8723be fwlps=0 swlps=0 ips=0
```

How do I get rid of all the drops?

Comment: Have you tried toggling the wifi switch or restarting network-manager `sudo service network-manager restart`? It doesn't fix your problem but might be easier than rebooting in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf

sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be
```

After the reboot the drops should never happen again.

Comment: I am facing same problem with ubuntu 14.04 and  lenevo Z50.
I don't  see rtl8723be.conf file in /etc/moprobe.d .

Answer (score 2):

One thing I think you are missing is that you haven't got the latest driver. I don't believe it is yet included in the kernel you installed. I'll post my complete solution below in case others are looking for this.

I had been struggling with this issue for months. Here's what finally worked for me and seems to be working for others on 14.04:

**Download the latest driver (you might have to install git first)**

```
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
```

**Change into the new directory you just created**

```
cd rtlwifi_new
```

**Compile and install the new driver**

```
make
sudo make install
```

**Edit the settings for the driver**

```
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0 swlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

It's probably a good idea to take a look at that file to make sure that worked. Some people say the "swlps=0" part of the command above is unnecessary. I'm not sure but it doesn't seem to be hurting anything.

Reboot.

**The next time your system updates the kernel, you may have to do this part again:**

```
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

I'd be curious to hear if others have tried this on releases other than 14.04 with success.

Good luck!