# Wireless network drops on Lenovo g50-80

Tags: 14.04, wireless, lenovo

My wireless network is dropping after certain minutes on my Lenovo g50-80 laptop. It requires a reboot to make all things work again.

I tried updating linux kernel headers and all those such stuffs, but still not working.

Comment: Do you know the exact type of the WiFi card? If not, please run: `lspci | grep -i wireless`

Comment: This thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/565562/wifi-dropping-on-lenovo-g50-70 could help you with some idea.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos